# Manually create Shopify session in console using shopify_token

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oauth, shopify

I have a store who installed my app, but the webhook didn't get created. Can I manually connect to the API using that shop's shopify_token so that I can manually create the webhook?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can (take a look at the [Webhook](https://docs.shopify.com/api/webhook) resource in the Shopify API). In Rails console, you'd do something like this:

```
shopify_session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(<shopify_domain>, <shop_token>)
ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(shopify_session)
shopify_shop = ShopifyAPI::Shop.current

ShopifyAPI::Webhook.create(topic: <event>, address: <your_app_endpoin>)
```

Answer (score 1):

You may try this solution. It's more cleaner and easier to use.

```
# app/models/shop.rb

def with_shopify!
  session = ShopifyAPI::Session.new(shopify_domain, shopify_token)
  ShopifyAPI::Base.activate_session(session)
end
```

In rails console you can write this:

```
Shop.first.with_shopify!
```